# Why multiplying the elements in first column of a matrix by k multiplies the determinant by k

Tags: matrices

My book asks:

> Explain in terms of volumes why multiplying all the elements in the
>   first column by constant $k$ multiplies the value of the determinant
>   by $k$ of $(a\space b\space c)$.

To which the answer is:

> Stretching factor by $k$ in one direction only multiplies volume by
>   $k$.

So to test it out I carried out:

$\begin{pmatrix}
    ka_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
    ka_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
    ka_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    y \\
    x \\
    z \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
    ka_1x+b_1y+c_1z \\
    ka_2x+b_2y+c_2z \\
    ka_3x+b_3y+c_3z \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Which to me (probably interpretation it wrong) seems to be a small increase in all directions relative to $kx$ which i believe would still increase the determinant by $k$ but doesn't really fit into the answer they've given me, i can't see any broken logic in my reasoning so would appreciate any help understanding my error.

Comment: also would said matrix applied to a cube lead to a parallel pipped shape where all sides increase as $x$ increases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a parallelepiped $\mathcal{P}$, and double just one side - like taking two copies of $\mathcal{P}$ - what happens to the volume?

Comment: This matrix doesn't change just one side of a parallel piped does it? I thought it changed all sides by a small amount. Because $x, y, z$ all changes values when i applied the matrix to the point.

Comment: @SonnyDaSilva-Peters, the correct interpretation is the following. You have three (column) vectors $a = [a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}]^{t}$ (meaning transpose), and similarly $b$, $c$. Then the volume of the parallelepiped whose vertices are $0, a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c$ is given by the absolute value of the determinant of your matrix. The matrix is not acting on anything here.

Comment: Okay i think I understand thank you